# Why backslash ( \ ) causes ValuesError when using CDLIB?

Tags: python, graph

I am working on community detection algorithms on graphs. I have an edge list that its nodes are strings such as: names, addresses,IDs and ,...
There was something interesting with edge list. When there is backslash ( \ ) in edgelist such as `\template1\`  the program raises this Error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:` but when I remove backslashes and `\template1\`  becames as `template1`  everything works well. Is there any way to handle and solve this problem? because I dont want to change the actual words in edge list and i dont want to remove backslashes.

I use this code to build a graph and detect communities:

```
from cdlib import algorithms
import networkx as nx
Txtfile = open("ProgramFolders/result/edgelist.txt", encoding='utf-8')
G = nx.read_weighted_edgelist(Txtfile)
Txtfile.close()

coms = algorithms.louvain(G)
```

and this is a small part of my edge list:

```
\template1\      \192.168.100.30
\template1\      200.02483421 
\template1\      \192.168.100.70
\template1\      //192.167.100.30:70/service
\template1\      \192.168
\template1\      //192.168.44
\template1\      240.54625187 
\template1\      //192.167.100/service
...
```

**Update**

this is the traceback log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vaio\PycharmProjects\community.py", line 315, in <module>
    coms = algorithms.louvain(G, weight='weight')
  File "C:\Users\vaio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\cdlib-0.2.4-py3.9.egg\cdlib\algorithms\crisp_partition.py", line 518, in louvain
  File "C:\Users\vaio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\cdlib-0.2.4-py3.9.egg\cdlib\classes\node_clustering.py", line 31, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\vaio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\cdlib-0.2.4-py3.9.egg\cdlib\classes\clustering.py", line 42, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\vaio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\cdlib-0.2.4-py3.9.egg\cdlib\classes\clustering.py", line 21, in __convert_back_to_original_nodes_names_if_needed
  File "C:\Users\vaio\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\cdlib-0.2.4-py3.9.egg\cdlib\classes\clustering.py", line 21, in <listcomp>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'template1\\'
```

I really appreciate answers which solves this problem